# PostgreSQL login with x509 certificate

Tags: postgresql, authentication, x509certificate

I have web application based on pyramid, where users authenticating themselves against Postgresql database with passwords.
Now I want to change login/password to smartcards. How can I login users to Postgres in such scenario ?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html

Comment: I know this document but there is no solution for my problem. In web application, there is no direct connection from user to database. There is web server and web application in the middle. The question is how to extend user-web server trust, to web server-database.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to create a function that will accept JWT or x509, validate it, create a "phantom user" that corresponds with the roles of that identity, then run the SQL with that user.

I'm not familiar with Pyramid, but it should be possible to configure or modify that framework to use such a strategy. Furthermore, a Public Web Service API endpoint can be defined, and then even a front-end javascript can directly query with SQL.